# Hidden Default Form Values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've got a simple form that I would like to be able to add a hidden value that is only used in the event the user doesn't enter a value. The values are for simple text input fields and can use HTML, PHP, JavaScript, JQuery, or any combination thereof. Let me explain further that the value attributes are already set to contain the values in the DB for that form currently. However, in the event there is no current value in the DB for that specific field and the user does not enter a value themselves, I would like a default value to be passed in the POST.

I've done some research and found examples of custom attributes, etc... but these will not work for me. As I'm using an array builder that passes all of the fields in the form as a single array to a new function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code shown below is the creation of the form... As you can see two separate fields are created redundantly for however many rounds exist within the tournament. I've also provided output HTML code of a two round form. In the event the DB has NULL values for the field in question, and if the user doesn't enter a value of his/her own, I would like to pass the value of "false".

```
                $rchkpos = array();
                $rchkscore = array();

                for ($i=0; $i<=$tournament['numRounds']; $i++)
                {
                    $rchkthis = array("$i" => "round".$i."pos");
                    $rchkthis2 = array("$i" => "round".$i."score");

                    $rchkpos = array_merge($rchkpos, $rchkthis);
                    $rchkscore = array_merge($rchkscore, $rchkthis2);

                    if ($i > 0)
                    {
                        $roundpos = $rchkpos[$i];
                        $roundscore = $rchkscore[$i];

                        if (!is_null($stats2[$roundpos])){
                            $roundposvar = "$stats2[$roundpos]";
                        }else{ 
                            $roundposvar = false;
                        }

                        if (!is_null($stats2[$roundscore])){ 
                            $roundscorevar = "$stats2[$roundscore]";
                        }else{ 
                            $roundscorevar = false;
                        }

                        $team_stats.="
                        <tr valign='top'>
                            <td align='center'>" . LANG_MAN_ROUND . " $i " . LANG_MAN_POSITION . "</td>     
                            <td class='alt1' align='center'>            
                                <input type='text' name='round[".$rchkpos[$i]."]' value='$stats2[$roundpos]' size='40' maxlength='5' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr valign='top'>
                            <td align='center'>" . LANG_MAN_ROUND . " $i " . LANG_MAN_SCORE . "</td>
                            <td class='alt1' align='center'>
                                <input type='text' name='round[".$rchkscore[$i]."]' value='$stats2[$roundscore]' size='40' maxlength='5' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>";
                    }
                }
```

Output HTML Example:

```
                 <tbody><tr valign="top">
                            <td align="center">Round 1 Position</td>        
                            <td align="center" class="alt1">            
                                <input type="text" maxlength="5" size="40" value="2" name="round[round1pos]">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td align="center">Round 1 Score</td>
                            <td align="center" class="alt1">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="5" size="40" value="false" name="round[round1score]">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td align="center">Round 2 Position</td>        
                            <td align="center" class="alt1">            
                                <input type="text" maxlength="5" size="40" value="false" name="round[round2pos]">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td align="center">Round 2 Score</td>
                            <td align="center" class="alt1">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="5" size="40" value="false" name="round[round2score]">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you post any code that shows what you have tried?

Comment: @cfs I've added the code, though I'm not sure it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can possibly do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="hidden" name="name_default" value="name_default" />
```

**PHP** (after form submit)

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $_POST['name'] = $_POST['name_default'];

}
```

Or make an aray like this:

```
$array_check = array('name', 'telephone', 'gender');

foreach($array_check AS $key => $value) {

    if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {

        $_POST[$value] = $_POST[$value."_default"];

    }    

}
```

Keep in mind that users can edit the values of the hidden inputs (with developer tools like Firebug), **always** check the input!

Comment: Thanks @GBRickJM, small typo.

Comment: I like this concept, I think I will use it... It will work nicely in conjunction with my existing script. I was hoping to get away with not adding another array to the functions parameters, but I think it will be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: You can make the solution more save when you load the default values from the database after the submit of the form. The default values don't have to be in the form then.

Answer (score 2):

Other possible approach is to set the default values in a dedicated property in each html input and then replace the value of the field before the post using jQuery:

```
// before post
$('input').each(function () {
if ($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultvalue'));
});
```

Comment: I understand the concept, I'm kind of new to JS/JQuery, since this is being done before the post... does it need a listener?

Comment: Yes it needs. You can put this in the action of the submit button or you can use an event handler for the submit action of the form itself. Check this link:
http://api.jquery.com/submit/